# Assigning ranks to items that vary in order

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a dataset from an online questionnaire. In this questionnaire, participants were asked to name 6 items. These items are represented with numbers from 1 to 6 (order of mention does not matter). Afterwards, participants were asked to rank those items from most important to least important (order here matters). Right now I have three columns "Named items", "Item ranked" and "Rank." The last column represents the position at which each case was ranked at. Thus, the idea would be to look at the number in the first column "Named item" and search for its position on the second column "Items Ranked" and return its position to the third column corresponding row.

Since the numbers go from 1 to 6, every six rows the process has to start again on the 7th row. I have a total of 186 participants, which means there's a total of 1116 items. What would be the most efficient way of doing this and preventing human error?

Here is an example of how the sheet looks like done manually:

```
+----------------------+-----------------------------+------+
| Order of named items | Items ranked (# = Identity) | Rank |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+------+
|                    1 |                           2 |    4 |
|                    2 |                           5 |    1 |
|                    3 |                           6 |    6 |
|                    4 |                           1 |    5 |
|                    5 |                           4 |    2 |
|                    6 |                           3 |    3 |
|                    1 |                           1 |    1 |
|                    2 |                           2 |    2 |
|                    3 |                           3 |    3 |
|                    4 |                           4 |    4 |
|                    5 |                           5 |    5 |
|                    6 |                           6 |    6 |
|                    1 |                           1 |    1 |
|                    2 |                           2 |    2 |
|                    3 |                           3 |    3 |
|                    4 |                           4 |    4 |
|                    5 |                           5 |    5 |
|                    6 |                           6 |    6 |
|                    1 |                           5 |    3 |
|                    2 |                           6 |    4 |
|                    3 |                           1 |    5 |
|                    4 |                           2 |    6 |
|                    5 |                           3 |    1 |
|                    6 |                           4 |    2 |
|                    1 |                           2 |    2 |
|                    2 |                           1 |    1 |
|                    3 |                           6 |    4 |
|                    4 |                           3 |    5 |
|                    5 |                           4 |    6 |
|                    6 |                           5 |    3 |
+----------------------+-----------------------------+------+
```

Comment: See if your online questionaire can export to a file format called CSV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this non volatile function:

```
=MATCH(A2,INDEX(B:B,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/6)*6+2):INDEX(B:B,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/6)*6+7),0)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much, this works. My partner and I were trying different formulas all night using vlookup mod and other stuff to no avail. :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 1st column starts at A2 and second column at B2 use this formula in C2 copied down

`=MATCH(A2,OFFSET(B$2,6*INT((ROWS(C$2:C2)-1)/6),0,6),0)`

`OFFSET` returns the 6 cell range required and `MATCH` finds the position of the relevant item within that

See screenshot below

[image]